# Slows down the iPad retina simulator 6.0

Tags: ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, retina-display

I have a game made in cocos2d for iPhone, I've adapted for iPad and works well if not retina.
When I run my game in the retina iPad simulator, the game is very slow, the images of the characters take a lot to load.
Why does this happen? Is the problem the simulator? Am I missing a line of code to run normal?
The code is exactly the iPhone and iPhone is great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simulator can have a very different performance profile than a device—in this case your computer’s graphics card might just be struggling to handle the large graphics context of the retina iPad screen. You should always do your performance testing on an actual device, particularly with apps like yours that make use of OpenGL.

Comment: More thanks, 
More thanks friend,I thought it might be a problem with the code, which when the ipad retina had to add something else. The problem is I have no way to test it on iPad Retina, so will update the app to have if I have no problem

Comment: Also, if you have something that relies on OpenGL ES (like cocos2d), performance may be worse than on the device due to the fact that the Simulator emulates certain features of the GPU in software rather than hardware. This can be far slower for certain types of operations, like certain kinds of fragment shaders.