# A strange frame rate with actions on retina iPad only

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Using actions with `cocos2d v2.0` it works perfect on all `iPhones` and regular iPad. but when testing the same code **only** on `iPad retina` simulator ,when the button is a x2 bigger, so all actions (scale,move etc) are seems like they missing some pixels in their movement( for example a moving sprite is go 1 -3 -5 instead of 1-2-3-4-5 , seems like low frame rate or jump pixels)

There is no memory issue, its just a simple page with simple action :

```
    id action=[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.5 scaleX:0.95 scaleY:1.1];
    id action1=[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.5 scaleX:1  scaleY:1 ];
    id seqb=[CCSequence actions:action,action1,  nil];
    id forever=[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:seqb];
    [play runAction:forever];
```

Why is it happens only in the retina display? does actions are not have the resolution for iPad retina -so they jumping on pixels ?
Do i have to enable the retina somewhere ? (it does get the -ipadhd image as retina and resize it)

**EDIT EDIT** 
I have read that :
[Slows down the iPad retina simulator 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718230/slows-down-the-ipad-retina-simulator-6-0)
and could see that maybe the mac processor is not handle that .

Well thats strange , i have the new macbook retina ,it has a strong processor, and i am sure more than an iPad, so how is that true that iPad can handle it but not the mac ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ignore the simulator, test on an actual device.

Note that the ipad retina simulator is really slow which is likely causing this issue.

Comment: problem is, that small studios, does not have all devices in the world :) we have ipad2 and iPad mini ... anyway , do you know that problem? because i haven't found any issue on that in google, and i searched a lot .

Comment: @Curnelious : there must be a truckload of q&a's around here regarding using the simulator for performance. I have apps clocking at 8-12 FPS on the simulator that run flawlessly on the puniest device. The simulator does not make use of the GPU (is emulated), so as it concerns graphics it can be very slow and erratic.

Comment: Same here.  The simulator can lull you either into thinking you have awesome power or terrible performance.  Nothing makes the software work like the hardware. I picked up an iPad 3 off ebay (just WiFi) just so I could test performance on it.  Also use an iPad 2, an iPhone 4, and a 5c.  I figure that covers the gamut...old and new.